# Getting NullpointerException some time when activity recreate in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my application one is a MainActivity which extends from CordovaActivity and other ConsoleActivity which extends from MainActivity. I have some object which i am use to initialize at  ConsoleActivity initWebView(). Here is code:
MainActivity:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

   WebView view = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    view.setWebViewClient(new SSLAcceptingWebViewClient(appView));
     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        view.clearCache(false);
        initWebView(); 
     }
     ...
```

ConsoleActivity:

```
public class ConsoleActivity extends MainActivity {
  @Override
  protected void initWebView() {
    settingManger =new SettingManager(ConsoleActivity.this);
    Util mJSUtil = new Util(this, appView);
```

((WebView)appView.getEngine().getView()).addJavascriptInterface(mJSUtil, "JSUtil");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/start.html");
    }

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
..
}
```

So when i start my application everthing work fine. but some time(my observation) when android kill this activity and it recreate again savedInstanceState is not null so that I unable to make a call to initWebView and settingManger object and Util not properly create and when I try to use them later on in ConsoleActivity getting an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myhome.myapp/com.myhome.myaoo.activity.ConsoleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.myapp.util.SettingsManager.getlog()' on a null object reference
```

Is there any workaround of this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use the details from the savedInstance and recreate the activity. But if you want to ignore the savedInstance in ConsoleActivity you can try overriding onCreate in ConsoleActivity and call `initWebView();` based on the savedInstance which gets passed into it.

Comment: Do you mean i have to use  if (savedInstanceState == null) { initWebView () in ConsoleActivity ? if yes then what is a difference by using this approach ?

Comment: What i meant is instead of changing the MainActivity which can affect other subclasses, you can override and ignore the savedInstance in the ConsoleActivity.